# Shared hosting with dedicated IP

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, ip-address, dedicated-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Can you please mention here if you know any shared hosting providers who give option to get a dedicated IP?  So far I know of one - Netfirms. Please list others if you know.

The reason why I am looking for such a thing is:

i) In most shared hosting plans, you end up getting better CPU/burst RAM than a VPS provided you don't abuse.

ii) Dedicated IP is good for SEO. For example, many times, you may get up getting an IP where some p*** sites are also hosted in shared hosting.

Comment: Where did you hear that shared IPs are worse for SEO than dedicated IPs? I know there was a lot of talk about it around 5 years ago, but nothign came of it and it was debunked as false.

Comment: I too am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most hosts offer dedicated IP address as an add-on for their shared webhosting services. For example, WestHost does, and so does HostGator. The reason almost all web hosts offer dedicated IP addresses is because you have to have a dedicated IP to have an SSL certificate.

Your assumption about getting better CPU and RAM bursts verses VPS is not true at all hosts. Worse, most of the time, whatever that maximum allowed amount is, it is not usually disclosed. Until your site gets forced offline, you won't know how close you are coming to hitting it.

Even worse than that, is that since that number is neither disclosed, nor guaranteed in your service agreement, it can change. A shared host running with plenty of room might indeed allow a big burst from your site, but if several sites on that shared host are bursting, the amount of available overhead will be lower and that same burst won't be allowed that time around and your site will end up offline.

Comment: Thank you. What you say indeed makes sense. Infact, the host which did give me lots of burst ram was relatively new and had very low server load. I guess its safe to go for a reliable VPS, given that sometimes VPS costs might turn out to be lower!

Answer (score 0):

I know that its not the best, but godaddy.com at one time did offer this.

Answer (score 0):

Arvixe.com allows you to get a dedicated IP for most (if not all) of their sharing plans. I believe it's an extra $2/month, but you'll want to verify that.